# Shall I use sync httpclient or async http client in Akka streams?

Tags: scala, stream, akka, httpclient

I am working on a pipeline of

```
Source(datafile)--> Flow(web scraping with entry in file)--> Flow(extraction of items form page) --> Flow(query to another services) --> Sink(cmp and summary)
```

Since Akka http client is not there yet, which http client lib in scala do you recommend? Can I use aysnc http client with Akka stream? Looks to me this is not the case. If so, which lib is the best choice for this kind of applications?

Comment: You could use [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) which uses async-http-client.

Answer (score 0):

The body parsing of Akka-Http now always returns a `Source` on its own.

Therefore use `Unmarshal` or `toStrict` to get access to the entity (body) of the response and use `mapAsync` to let Akka handle the concurrency/callback:

```
// Create your HttpRequests objects
var in = Sink....
// Use Akka to connect
var http.superPool[NotUsed]
// Parse the response
val httpResponse2HttpStrict = Flow[(Try[HttpResponse], NotUsed)].mapAsync(1)({case(response, _) => response match {
  case Success(response) => response.entity.toStrict(timeout)
  case Failure(e) => handleErrorHere(e)
})

// Connect it
in ~> httpClient ~> httpResponse2HttpStrict ~> Flow[HttpEntity].map(entity => processTheBody(entity)
```

The flow API is described here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#Flow-Based_Variant